# How can I use a JB Burrows wireless base station with a Logitech mouse?

Tags: usb, drivers, mouse, bluetooth

I bought a JB Burrows wireless mouse a few months ago, and the light defocussed after a while (I think, buttons were fine but tracking only worked on glossy surfaces). I replaced it with a Logitech M705 which *should* be much better...but I either lost the base station or it never had one to begin with (can't clearly remember whether I saw it in the packet, have looked mostly everywhere at home).

I *do* still have the JB Burrows base station, though. Could I flash it with Logitech firmware? If I can, how would I do that? Neither station uses a generic wireless connection, so using the Burrows station without changing the firmware wouldn't work.

Comment: *"as far as I know there isn't any physical difference"* -- Any differences in the silicon are invisible to the plain eye.  And you don't even have the Logitech base station to actually perform a side-by-side comparison, so how do you *"know"* this?

Comment: To be honest...I don't, it's a guess because I couldn't imagine any reason they'd be different. I'll edit that to something better. Are you suggesting that swapping the drivers is impossible/won't fix anything?

Comment: *" I couldn't imagine any reason they'd be different."*  -- So how many  devices have you taken apart and/or performed firmware updates?  The exterior case of products is a poor indicator of internal hardware compatibility.  Manufacturers are known to change the internal hardware whenever they want, e.g. to reduce cost.  This generates product versions, each with its own unique firmware.  Without the Logitech base station, you have no clue of what you're trying to replace/emulate.  You would have to reverse engineer the device using the Logitech mouse or from a Logitech firmware binary.

Comment: None, that's why I'm asking the question. From what you're saying coercing the JB Burrows station to work with a different mouse is impossible, and if it isn't impossible it's way beyond my ability. I'll keep looking for the Logitech usb instead.

Comment: Hey, sorry for coming off so harshly before, I definitely came into this naive and maybe a bit arrogant. I was expecting to replace the Burrows firmware with a Logitech binary, but I'd forgotten how proprietary that would be and how much the hardware could vary between vendors. You're right that it's either impossible or very messy, and mostly pointless since Logitech sells their stations separately anyway (https://www.amazon.com/Logitech-910-005235-USB-Unifying-Receiver/dp/B072JW9LT8).

Comment: I couldn't fit this in the last comment, but just wanted to admit I should have formatted my question better. I didn't research much before this question, and I have basically no experience with hardware at all, so I made assumptions (USB stations won't vary *that* much, firmware updates are trivial) that don't match up to reality. I'll try to edit again now.

Comment: All of those mouse-specific receiver/transmitter combos are highly proprietary and—unless someone knows something I don’t—it’s not like you can just flash new firmware on one thing to make it behave like another. You need a direct replacement for the item and often that just means buying a whole new mouse. Welcome to the world of disposable tech!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use them interchangeably.  The Logitech M705 uses Logitech's proprietary Unifying receiver and encryption.  It does not use Bluetooth technology.

You can purchase a replacement receiver from Logitech's [website](http://buy.logitech.com/store/logib2c/en_US/DisplayCategoryProductListPage/categoryid.55766800) for $15 in the US.  However, this is a rip off, as you will see in the paragraph below.

You can also find the receiver with Logitech Unifying mice in stores like Best Buy.  I have seen the mouse/receiver combo for at little as $10.  Obviously, you can purchase this and get the receiver - and a low end mouse - for 2/3 the price of buying just the receiver from Logitech.

Additionally, you can sometimes find Logitech keyboards and mice in places like Goodwill.  I have picked up extra Logitech receivers (with keyboards and mice I dispose of) for as little as $2.  Often people just donate the keyboards and mice and do not think to include the receiver, so you will only find them donated in their original boxes.  Its a long shot, but its far cheaper than paying full price.

FYI - Unless a Logitech wireless product *specifically* says it uses Bluetooth, it uses the its proprietary Unifying technology.

Comment: Lol what?  A random downvote and delete?  Gotta love some of the people on SuperUser...

Comment: So the hardware *is* fundamentally incompatible then...I'll wait a few days to see if the bundled receiver turns up somewhere and buy a new one if it doesn't. Thanks for the answer! :)